# Errors on deployed Android App?

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, android-emulator

I have an app that I have tested on a number of different Android Versions via an emulator and a handful of devices.  Everything works fine on the app and then I publish it via the android market.

I know have a user contacting me that the app is "freezing" on a certain page.  He tells me the phone and he tell me the Android Version.  I haven't tested on the phone he has mentioned.  My question is how or what information can I get from the user or from the users phone to figure out why it's "freezing"?  I feel helpless unless I have that phone in hand to recreate the error?  Is there anything I can do to avoid such situations in the future?

Also..what is the best way to test all the devices that are out on the market these days?

Thanks

Comment: Tony, when an app crashes (does the freeze cause it to crash?), the user is presented with the option to provide feedback to the developer, which includes a stack trace. Tell the user that he needs to submit this next time it happens, so you can debug the problem.

Comment: Thanks Phil..I'm still trying to get information from the user.  Specifically is the the screen freezing or is it truly a crash.  I'm assuming if he submits the error I can then see it via the android developer market.  I'm a newbie to Android apps; this is great information to know.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Its not feasible to test on all devices, specially for small developers. I normally test my app on all the supported API levels and corresponding screen size and resolution on emulators. Another think that I found it handy is to use error reporting code in the app itself to get error reports from the field. I use [ACRA][1][1]: http://code.google.com/p/acra/
and found it to be very useful. 
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the advice...I didn't think it would be possible to test on "every device".  I will look into ACRA.